# Jquery load function getting stuck after first load

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Hi I have this sample code to load random quotes.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
  //Selecting Random quotes from database --randomquotes.php
  require('dbconnection.php');
  // $temp=10;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM db.q order by rand() LIMIT 1";
  $res = mysql_query($sql,$con);
  while ($res1=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
  { 
    print "<em>".$res1['quote']."</em>";
  }
?>
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="class_box_shadow_quote">
<?php
  require('randomquotes.php');
?>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
<script>
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
      $j(".class_box_shadow_quote").load('randomquotes.php');
    }, 7000);
  });
</script>
```

This code is working well for the first time , but is getting stuck on second quote and is not changing the quote.
Also everytime i see the second quote to be the same always.
What is the problem . Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the output is being cached by jQuery. You can try with caching disabled.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $j.ajax({
        url: 'randomquotes.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $j(".class_box_shadow_quote").html(data);
        }
    });
}, 7000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a random seed at the end of your URL to avoid browser caching, like so:

```
    $(".class_box_shadow_quote").load('randomquotes.php?s=' + (Math.Random() * 1000000))
```

Comment: Wow this is new to me...but the previous solution was easy to avoid caching .

Comment: Sometimes, manipulating the cache headers don't work. I've run into that problem several times. It's getting better though. :)

Comment: Actually `cache: false` does the same. It adds a randomizer to the url.